# Informatica lookup override group by not equal to condition

Tags: sql, oracle, informatica, informatica-powercenter, information-extraction

I have a lookup transformation and there is sql override. I m simplying query for understanding purpose

Its something like

```
select empno,sum(sal)
from tab1
group by empno;
```

Now, my requirement is based on source data I need to apply a filter condition which is something like this :-

> If source table date for the current row - src_dt and tran_dt (from tab1-lookup tbale)
>   column is match/equal then exclude that row for the calculation.

As sql override is group by, how I can achieve this functionality with less modification in the current code

Comment: @Marek Grzenkowicz code is in prod currently and current code is not having tran_dt column. We need to do this modification in the current code and filter records based on it as mentioned in the question

Comment: Why don't you do the logic in the map with an aggregation transformation ?

Comment: do you mean `group by empno`? What calculation are you doing in your mapping?

Comment: @sagi sorry for late reply... I was on holiday.. current lookup override query(which is group by) I need to modify.. I need to filter out few records before doing group by... (if emp_sal_code is match with the source_sal_code) then need to exclude/filter that records and then need to do the sum. Yes, I can do that with aggregation transformation, I m just thinking is there any way to handle this with existing lookup only modification.. code is in prod and this came as a new requirement.

Comment: @Samik have mentioned more information in my above comment, and yes I meant "group by empno". I have done the edits in question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Compare id from source and id from lkp then get the tr date from lkp and bring the src date from source qualifier and add a filter transformation compare the dates as required to filter the records.

Comment: Yeah it can be this way. However, my question is - is there any way to change in the lookup transformation only ? Its prod code and need to do minimum changes here.....

Comment: Lookup is a passive transformation you can not filter the records which are coming in from source. If you can have unmatched records as null or some default value in your target add > and < condition in lookup ...Covert your lookup override to analytical function to calculate sum (eg select sum(aggcol) over (partition by group by col order by col)

Answer (score 0):

select a.empno,a.total_sal, b.tran_dt
(select empno,sum(sal) as total_sal,
from tab1 a, 
group by a.empno) a,
(select empno,tran_dt
from tab1) b
where a.empno = b.empno